# On OS X, what is pubsubagent and why does it connect so many places?

Tags: macos

I use Little Snitch to monitor network connections on OS X, and I frequently see attempts by something called pubsubagent to connect to many varying sites.  What is this program for and why does it use so many connections?

According to [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/132910/2008/04/pubsubagent.html) it's used by .me sync to synchronize RSS feeds and bookmarks.  But I don't have any RSS feeds.  And if it's synching bookmarks, then why is it going to places like 'l.google.com' (and many more random ones) instead of just to .me?

Comment: Same "problem" here. PubSubAgent want's to connect to a site I visited about an hour before, but never had a RSS or anything similar of this site. Some say, PubSubAgent also keeps the "Top Sites" images up-to-date and thus connect to that sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail comes setup with several default RSS feeds. Delete them if you don't want them.

I believe you can also just whack the entire ~/Library/PubSub folder and get rid of everything that could possibly be using the PubSub framework.