# "PubSubAgent" wants to connect to images.apple.com. What is that program and what dose it send to apple?

Tags: macos, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On OS X, what is pubsubagent and why does it connect so many places?](https://superuser.com/questions/131077/on-os-x-what-is-pubsubagent-and-why-does-it-connect-so-many-places)

I'm kinda new to OS X, and I have a program called "PubSubAgent" that wants to connect to apple. What will be sent if I allow it? What dose the program do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Help: [Mac OS X 10.5: About the PubSub Agent](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1770)

> The PubSub agent syncs the RSS read/unread status of bookmarked RSS feeds between computers using Mac OS X 10.5 that are syncing bookmarks via MobileMe Sync.

This also applies to newer versions of OS X.

I guess this would also apply to the default RSS feeds that are configured in Apple Mail (in addition to those from Safari). Delete them if you like. There's nothing to worry about though.

[image]

Comment: See my update, simply remove them from Mail.app or Safari.

Comment: I have some more stuff like that. Should I open a question for every one? or one new question with all?

Comment: I wouldn't open a single question about each one. Please do some research before though. Most Apple services are explained fairly well on various sites on the web.

Answer (score 1):

User *slhck* already answered what the PubSub Agent does. Another option to unsubscribe selectively from certain feeds is using the command line (Terminal). To find out which feeds the PubSub Agent has subscribed to:

```
pubsub list feeds
```

To unsubscribe from a feed:

```
pubsub unsubscribe 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/si_topstories.rss'
```